# Getting 'null' when concatenating chars into string array

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char [][] charArr = 
    {   {'a','b','c'},
        {'d','e','f'},
        {'g','h','i'}
    };

    String [] stringA = charToString(charArr);

    for (int i = 0; i < stringA.length; i++) 
    {
        System.out.println(stringA[i]);
    }

}

public static String [] charToString(char [][] array)
{
    String [] stringArr = new String [array.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
    {
        stringArr[i] += "";
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        {
            stringArr[i] += array[i][j];
        }
    }
    return stringArr;
```

Currently I am getting an output of:

nullabc

nulldef

nullghi

I am trying to concatenate each column of the 2d array charArr into a string and into each element of the 1d array called stringArr. I'm not sure where null is coming from though or what I'm doing wrong...

Appreciate the help!

Comment: One liner for that method `return Arrays.stream(array).map(String::new).toArray(String[]::new)`

Comment: Can you explain this to me?

Comment: [Explained here in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53624149/1746118)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
stringArr[i] += "";
```

this line is causing the issue, which is equivalent to
`stringArr[i] = stringArr[i]+ "";`
you are declaring a null string and appending a empty string to it, simply change it to

```
stringArr[i] = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

When this line execute

```
String [] stringArr = new String [array.length];
```

It create an array and initialize array element with null.
So when you perform concat(`stringArr[i] += ""`) it add null then data.

You need to change your method like this-

```
public static String [] charToString(char [][] array)
    {
        String [] stringArr = new String [array.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) 
        {
            if(stringArr[i]==null){
                stringArr[i]="";
            }
            stringArr[i] += "";
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
            {
                stringArr[i] += array[i][j];
            }
        }
        return stringArr;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not perhaps an exact fix for your code, but can take advantage of the `String` constructor which accepts a character array as input.

```
char [][] charArr = {
    {'a','b','c'},
    {'d','e','f'},
    {'g','h','i'}
};

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0; i < charArr.length; ++i) {
    if (i > 0) sb.append("\n");
    sb.append(new String(charArr[i]));
}
System.out.println(sb);

abc
def
ghi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// < java 8
public static String[] charToString(char[][] arr) {
    String[] res = new String[arr.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        res[i] = new String(arr[i]);

    return res;
}

// >= java 8
public static String[] charToString(char[][] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).map(String::new).toArray(String[]::new);
}
```

**Input:**

```
{
    { 'a', 'b', 'c' },
    { 'd', 'e', 'f' },
    { 'g', 'h', 'i' }
}
```

**Output:**

```
abc
def
ghi
```

**Notes:**

1. Bad practice to concatenate strings with loop; do use `StringBuilder` instead;
2. It is better to use out-of-box method, like. `new String(char value[])` instead of build it using `StringBuilder`.
3. Streams is good, but sometimes it is too hard to read; do not hesitate to use POJO and loops in case it looks more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Using streams one could update the method as:

```
private static String [] charToString(char[][] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array) //forms a Stream<char[]> (all your rows)
            .map(String::new) // maps the char[] to String forming Stream<String>
            .toArray(String[]::new); // converts the stream to array String[]
}
```

and further use it as :

```
char[][] charArr =
            {{'a', 'b', 'c'},
                    {'d', 'e', 'f'},
                    {'g', 'h', 'i'}
            };

Arrays.stream(charToString(charArr)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

**Output**

> ```
> abc
> def
> ghi
> ```